# A question about thread.Sleep() , thread.Join()

Tags: c#, multithreading, join, sleep

There is a code as below, the question is:
which player(s) will be written to the terminal first

I can easily understand the function of Start(), and Join() which means immediately starts the thread  . However, I am not sure what players will be written to the terminal first. My understanding is, it could be threadE, threadC, threadA, did not get the point to find the correct answers.

If anyone has a clue? thanks.

```
class Player
{
    private readonly string tag;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.tag = name;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.Write(tag + ",");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread threadA = new Thread(new Player("A").Run);
        Thread threadB = new Thread(new Player("B").Run);
        Thread threadC = new Thread(new Player("C").Run);
        Thread threadD = new Thread(new Player("D").Run);
        Thread threadE = new Thread(new Player("E").Run);


        threadE.Start(); 
        threadC.Start();
        threadA.Start();
        threadC.Join();  
        threadB.Start();
        threadA.Join();
        threadD.Start();
        threadB.Join();
        threadD.Join();
        threadE.Join();
    }
}
```

Comment: All that can be said for certain is that B definitely happens after C, and D definitely happens after C and A. Everything else is implementation-defined, and may change on every run, depending on what the scheduler is doing

Comment: It is a race, you can't assume one thread completes before another without synchronization.  The only guarantee you have is that C appears before B and D before A, thanks to the Join() calls, that's all.

Comment: Any time you need a program to do certain things in a certain order, that's a sign that maybe those things should all be done in the same thread. The entire point of using multiple threads is to allow things to happen [_concurrently_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)). But concurrency, by its very definition, is incompatible with the idea of things happening in a definite, predictable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans mentioned, it's a race. There are only a few things we can say about execution order.

Don't let the `Sleep` fool you. It doesn't guarantee anything. By its nature it's not really accurate, so, starting 2 `Sleeps` at the same time can easily result in one being 3ms faster than the other.

Lets break down the code.

```
//E, C and A start simultaneously.
//the order in which they complete is unpredictable.
threadE.Start(); 
threadC.Start();
threadA.Start();

//We wait on C here. Note that A and E might not be completed yet.
threadC.Join();  

//B starts after C completes. Possibly E and E are not finished yet.
//While unlikely (due to the sleep), this B can complete even before E and A completes.
//the only thing guaranteed is that B will start after C completes.
threadB.Start();

//Now we wait till A completes
//Most likely it's already done
threadA.Join();

//D will start here.
//Again, D might finish before B
threadD.Start();

//now we wait till everything is done.
threadB.Join();
threadD.Join();
threadE.Join();
```

---

So, his is easily verifiable. Note: if you run this yourself and you play with the value of `Sleep` a bit, you'll note the smaller the value (about 2~3 ms) the less predictable this will become. Also CPU load might affect the outcome for parallel operations.

Note that parallelism and Threads is not as trivial as it seems. In the end you have a finite number of CPUs and Cores - which needs to dived the instructions causing, depending on order and load cause variations in the outcome.

In the end there is no single answer about the order of WriteLine execution.

Comment: Much appreciated everyone , especially @Stefan !